# Understanding bytecode generated for a simple java class

Tags: java, bytecode, jvm-bytecode

I am following this [blog](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JavaCodeToByteCode_PartOne.html) to study java to bytecode & I have generated bytecode for this SimpleClass.

```
public class SimpleClass {

    public int simpleF = 5;


}
```

I understand the bytecode positions as below

- 0 is for 'this'
- 1 is for calling the constructor of superclass
  Object.
- 4  -- ?
- 5 for value 5
- 6 pop from stack and assign 5 to
  variable.

But I do not understand `aload_0` at position 4 and its purpose ?

```
// Compiled from SimpleClass.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
public class SimpleClass {

  // Field descriptor #6 I
  public int simpleF;

  // Method descriptor #8 ()V
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 1
  public SimpleClass();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [10]
     4  aload_0 [this]
     5  iconst_5
     6  putfield SimpleClass.simpleF : int [12]
     9  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 2]
        [pc: 4, line: 4]
        [pc: 9, line: 2]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: SimpleClass
}
```

Comment: I can only suggest you look up the JVM Specification, where every opcode is explained one to a page. Too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aload_0` is there to push in the stack the reference the current class in the statement that set the local non-static field `simpleF` to 5.

```
[this.]simpleF=5
```

---

From http://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref-putfield.html

> putfield sets the value of the field identified by `<field-spec>` in
>   objectref (a reference to an object) to the single or double word
>   value on the operand stack.

Answer (score 0):

For the JVM to execute almost anything it must push things into the execution stack , aload_0 is used to load an object from the local variables array (position 0 ) to the execution stack , for instance methods position 0 always refers to this which is a reference to the current object .

More information can be found in this article : 
http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JavaCodeToByteCode_PartOne.html